# Troubles to open property of publication in CME after installing Translate Manager in SDL Web8

Tags: web8, translation-manager

I installed Translate Manager in SDL Web8 and have modified Translation.xml according to the documentation of SDL Web8.
But when I intended to configure the source & target content in CME, I couldn't open the property of publication. Folders' property could be opened.
The error message shown in CME is post below:
[image]

There is no endpoint about TranslationManager in Web.config. Should I add them in it?(SDL Web8's documentation does not mention this step.)

Any idea of solving this would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is "Tridion Translation Manager" window service running?

Comment: And check the "Tridion Content Manager Service Host" service as well, as that is the one that hosts the net.tcp endpoint.

Comment: Also - check the config on your CM and check that the client-side creates the same **type** of binding. Also double-check the net.tcp address across all config points.

Comment: We had similar issue on one of our projects.
We had to update following config files after installation
%SDL_WEB_HOME%\bin\TcmServiceHost.exe.config
%SDL_WEB_HOME%\bin\TcmWorkflowAgent.exe.config
%SDL_WEB_HOME%\web\WebUI\WebRoot\Web.config
Translation Manager Installation puts localhost in these files instead of IPs or hostnames, after we reverted all config files to point to the server hostname issue was resolved.

Comment: Thanks all! I checked config files you told me and modified the localhost. It really works.